# Automatically convert keywords to links in php

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to convert specific keywords in text, which are stored in array, to the links.

Example text:

```
$text='This text contains many keywords, but also formated <a href="#keywords" title="keywords">keywords</a>.'
```

So now I want to convert the word **keywords** to the `<a href="#keywords" title="keywords">#keywords</a>`.

I used the very simple preg_replace function

```
preg_replace('/keywords/i',' <a href="#keywords">keywords</a> ',$text);
```

but obviously it converts to link also the string **already** formatted as a link, so I get a messy html like:

```
$text='This text contains many <a href="#keywords" title="keywords">keywords</a>, but also formated <a href="#<a href="#keywords" title="keywords">keywords</a>" title="<a href="#keywords" title="keywords">keywords</a>"><a href="#keywords" title="keywords">keywords</a></a>.'
```

Expected result:

```
$text='This text contains many <a href="#keywords" title="keywords">keywords</a>, but also formated <a href="#keywords" title="keywords">keywords</a>.'
```

Any suggestions?
THX

**EDIT**

We are one step from the perfect function, but still not working well in this case:

```
$text='This text contains many keywords, but also formated 
       <a href="http://www.keywords.com/keywords" title="keywords">keywords</a>.'
```

In this case it replaces also the word `keywords` in the href, so we again get the messy code like

```
 <a href="http://www.<a href="http://www.keywords.com/keywords" title="keywords">keywords</a>.com/<a href="http://www.keywords.com/keywords" title="keywords">keywords</a>" title="keywords">keywords</a>
```

Comment: Just my two cents, but since an href of '#something' would actually be a valid reference, I suggest using something else, for example a percentage sign, so that you don't some day accidentically replace an ordinary link.

Comment: actually that is just an example to show the the word keywords can occur also in the href="".

Comment: That just reinforces my point. You ought to re-read what I said. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not great with regular expressions, but maybe this one will work:

```
/[^#>"]keywords/i
```

What I think it will do is ignore any instances of `#keywords`, `>keywords`, and `"keywords` and find the rest.

---

**EDIT**:

After testing it out, it looks like that replaces the space before the word as well, and doesn't work if `keywords` is the beginning of the string. It also didn't preserve original capitalization. I have tested this one, and it works perfectly for me:

```
$string = "Keywords and keywords, plus some more keywords with the original <a href=\"#keywords\" title=\"keywords\">keywords</a>.";
$string = preg_replace("/(?<![#>\"])keywords/i", "<a href=\"#keywords\">$0</a>", $string);
echo $string;
```

The first three are replaced, preserving the original capitalization, and the last one is left untouched. This one uses a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) and [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#usebackrefinregex).

---

**EDIT 2:**

OP edited question. With the new example provided, the following regex will work:

```
$string = 'This text contains many keywords, but also formated <a href="http://www.keywords.com/keywords" title="keywords">keywords</a>.';
$string = preg_replace("/(?<![#>\".\/])keywords/i", "<a href=\"http://www.keywords.com/keywords\" title=\"keywords\">$0</a>", $string);
echo $string;

// outputs: This text contains many <a href="http://www.keywords.com/keywords" title="keywords">keywords</a>, but also formated <a href="http://www.keywords.com/keywords" title="keywords">keywords</a>.
```

This will replace all instances of `keywords` that are not preceded by `#`, `>`, `"`, `.`, or `/`.

Comment: @JKirchartz: Thanks, didn't know about that site. After trying it out, I found some flaws with my answer...see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, this looks great, but still has one bug. Could you please see the **edit** in my questions for further info? thx

Comment: @Travesty3 thanks a lot, second edit worked fine (just added \- to the regex, but thats just a small edit) :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem:

The keyword could be inside the href, the title, or the text of the link, and anywhere in there (like if the keyword was `sanity` and you already had `href="insanity"`. Or even worse, you could have a non-keyword link that happens to contain a keyword, something like:

```
<a href="http://example.org/">Click here to find more keywords and such!</a>
```

In the above example, even though it fits every other possible criteria (it's got spaces before and after being the easiest one to test for), it still would result in a link within a link, which I think breaks the internet.

Because of this, you need to use `lookaheads` and `lookbehinds` to check if the keyword is wrapped in a link. But there is one catch:  lookbehinds have to have a defined pattern (meaning no wild cards).

I thought I'd be the hero and show you the easy fix for your issue, which would be something to the effect of:

```
'/(?<!\<a.?>)[list|of|keywords](?!\<\/a>)/'
```

Except you can't do that because the lookbehind in this case has that wildcard. Without it, you end up with a super greedy expression.

So my proposed alternative is to use regex to find all link elements, then `str_replace` to swap them out with a placeholder, and then replacing them with the placeholder at the end.

Here's how I did it:

```
$text='This text contains many keywords, but also formated <a href="#keywords" title="keywords">keywords</a>.';
$keywords = array('text', 'formatted', 'keywords');

//This is just to make the regex easier
$keyword_list_pattern = '['. implode($keywords,"|") .']';

// First, get all matching keywords that are inside link elements
preg_match_all('/<a.*' . $keyword_list_pattern . '.*<\/a>/', $text, $links);
$links = array_unique($links[0]);  // Cleaning up array for next step.

// Second, swap out all matches with a placeholder, and build restore array:
foreach($links as $count => $link) {
     $link_key = "xxx_{$count}_xxx";
     $restore_links[$link_key] = $link;
     $text = str_replace($link, $link_key, $text);
}

// Third, we build a nice replacement array for the keywords:

foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
        $keyword_links[$keyword] = "<a href='#$keyword'>$keyword</a>";
}

// Merge the restore links to the bottom of the keyword links for one mass replacement:

$keyword_links = array_merge($keyword_links, $restore_links);

$text = str_replace(array_keys($keyword_links), $keyword_links, $text);

echo $text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your RegEx so that it only targets keywords with a space in front. Since the formatted keywords do no contain a space. Here is an example.

```
$text = preg_replace('/ keywords/i',' <a href="#keywords">keywords</a>',$text);
```

Comment: yes i tried, but it still can be withni another link with a space before, so it will mix two link together. thx